# Service Reference return value size issue

Tags: wcf, web-services, reflection

I have a Web Service method which returns a list of objects `List<T>`

When the the length of the list is 9000 objects or so, the service returns this list well, but when the length is like 12000 or more objects, the service returns an error:

The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

`System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FailureException: System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at .$Type.httprequest.webRespBase@162@162(DelegatingHttpReq x@162, Unit _unit)
   at .$Type.httprequest.webRespBase@162@162(DelegatingHttpReq x@162, Unit _unit)
   at Storm.Types.WebHttp.DelegatingHttpReq.GetResponse()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at ServiceLogic.LoadRestriccionCanalPlano(String CodRuta, String CodTipoRuta)

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Storm.UI.Forms.FormMainOps.clo@651.Invoke(Object[] methodParams@41)
   at .$Type.bgworker.run@51@57_2.Invoke(DoWorkEventArgs dArgs)
   at .$Type.bgworker.run@51@57_1.Invoke(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)`

I've tried changing the `maxBufferSize` `maxBufferPoolSize` `maxReceivedMessageSize` `maxStringContentLength` `maxArrayLength` etc in the binding configuration on the Web.config, but it still not working.

Any other ideas?

Comment: FYI, it looks like you're using a Service Reference, not a Web Reference. That's the right move, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

I've already found a solution in this post
[The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285345/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-the-connection-was-closed-unexpectedly)