# Unexpected closing connection in transition data from wcf to client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, entity-framework-5, ado.net-entity-data-model

I use `WCF` service for implementing getting data from database (using `Entity Framework` and `LINQ` on the service side). But when the service returns data I receive error: `The underlying connection was closed. The connection was closed unexpectedly`. How can I bypass it ?

Comment: do you return a strongly typed object?

Comment: Could you please include the code that is giving you trouble. Include the call to your service and the return.

Comment: Yes, I return a strongly typed object.

Comment: The trouble occurs not in the code but in process of data transition. I call my service like this: `var result = MyService.GiveResults()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not returning a strongly typed object, you have to change it to a strongly typed object. When you return an object, it has to be serialized as XML. And the serializer doesn't know how to serialise an object of type `object` or an anonymous type, because it doesn't know what type of object it has to serialise or what the properties are of the class, etc.

Comment: The service returns a strongly typed object.

Comment: Can you please include some code and which line you're being thrown the exception?

Comment: The error occurs when I call my service: MyClass result = MyService.GiveResult()

Comment: Do the answers in this link help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285345/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-the-connection-was-closed-unexpectedly