# The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly. Data is too big?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have got a server/client relationship where the client pulls an ArrayList from the server. If I set the server to always send an empty ArrayList then I don't get this error. So clearly the problem is that my data is too big for the connection and that it's closing before all the data can get through.

I have looked into this issue and I have added the features suggested by this question/answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/285542/3036134 Many solutions suggest the same thing.

I believe that I have implemented something incorrectly (I think it's most likely the Service Behaviour MaxItemsInObjectGraph as I am still getting the same error. I unfortunately can't figure out what's wrong with it though. Here's my code:

The error I'm receiving:

```
CommunicationException was unhandled. The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
```

My WCF Service Code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IModelData
{
    [OperationContract]
    ArrayList GetData();
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 2147483647)]
public class ModelDataClient
{
    ChannelFactory<IModelData> HttpFactory;
    IModelData HttpProxy;

    public ModelDataClient()
    {
        HttpFactory = new ChannelFactory<IModelData>(
            new BasicHttpBinding(),
            new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8000/ModelData"));

        HttpProxy = HttpFactory.CreateChannel();
    }

    public ArrayList GetData()
    {
        return HttpProxy.GetData();
    }
}

[ServiceBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 2147483647)]
public class ModelDataServer : IModelData
{
    public delegate ArrayList GetData();
    public GetData _GetData { get; set; }

    public ModelDataServer()
    {
    }

    public ArrayList GetData()
    {
        return _GetData();
    }
}
```

My Client Side Code:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{  
    private ModelDataClient Client;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Client = new ModelDataClient();
    }

    private void Refresh()
    {
        ArrayList dataList = Client.GetData();
        // ********** ERROR POINTS TO LINE ABOVE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

        // do something with datalist
    }
}
```

My Server Side Code:

```
public partial class ScraperForm : Form
{
    ServiceHost Host;
    ModelDataServer DataServer;

    ArrayList Data;

    public ScraperForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        #region Start Data Server
        DataServer = new ModelDataServer();
        DataServer._GetData = new ModelDataServer.GetData(this.GetData);

        BasicHttpBinding bhttpb = new BasicHttpBinding();

        bhttpb.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
        bhttpb.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
        bhttpb.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 32;
        bhttpb.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 8388608;
        bhttpb.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 16384;
        bhttpb.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 4096;
        bhttpb.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 16384;


        Host = new ServiceHost(DataServer, new Uri[]
            {
                new Uri("http://localhost:8000")
            });

        Host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IModelData),
            bhttpb,
            "ModelData");

        Host.Open();

        Data = new ArrayList();
    }

    private void CloseSever()
    {
        Host.Close();
    }

    public void UpdateData() // Run on a timer
    {
        ArrayList Data = new ArrayList()

        // Update Data
    }

    public ArrayList GetData() // This is called by server which is called by client
    {
        return Data;           // no error if I return new ArrayList();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Would the problem be being caused by not having DataContract/DataMembers?

**UPDATE**
I have rebuilt my new implementation from the ground up using this tutorial (and the related ones): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2013/10/28/wcf-programming-how-to-write-a-client-app-that-connects-to-a-wcf-service.aspx (For anyone interested).

Instead of using an ArrayList (lots of unboxing) and a Typed List (comes out as an array if used with WCF), I have instead opted to pass my data using a string with the following format: 
"~" to denote the start of a new member of the list
"," to denote the end of one of the datatypes in my custom one.
So it might look like "~NAME,1.29,1,4,123.1~NAME,1.23,3,1,13.2" etc. I would suggest people who want to use lists use this instead.

I have run into a new problem with my new implementation, likely the same/similar problem. Please see my new question: [Object reference not set to an instance of an object - WCF Service and Delegates (WCF Hosted before Delegate is instantiated)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715604/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-wcf-service-and-delegates)

Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: I believe the server *and client* have limits.

Comment: Yuck! Why `ArrayList`? Do you really need a collection of arbitrary items?

Comment: @ta.speot.is yes, I believe the above code sets the limits. Do you think I am sending too much data for what I've set here? I believe these are set to the max

Comment: Sets the limits on the server, sure.

Comment: My "Data" is a list of my own data type called "RFData", it consists of several doubles,  ints and 1 string. The list typically contains 10-30 of these. I am using arraylist because I've read its faster than a typed list for custom datatypes.

Comment: I doubt it is because the data is too big, but lets not speculate, if you enable diagnostics you will be able to see the exception in WCF that causes the problem.

Comment: @markmnl I will look into enabling diagnostics. But if the issue was not the size why would it not throw this error with an empty ArrayList?

Comment: I believe the problem is the fact that `ArrayList` when populated consists of user-defined types that are not defined for exchange within the model.

Comment: @DerekW Because ArrayList comes out of WCF as Object[], and typed list comes out as an array of data, I opted to send it through a string and then put it into an arraylist on the other end. Please see the update for what this string looks like. Do you think this is a good solution? Or can you suggest another one?

Comment: @Watson: WCF is designed to be consumed by any client. Meaning you could have a client written in Java that consumes a WCF Service. The reason why it turns out as an `Array` by default and not a `List` is that `List` is a .NET type. However, if your clients are going to be built in .NET, then use this as leverage and when you generate your proxy specify the 'Collection type' argument as `System.Collections.Generic.List`. The default for this parameter is `System.Array` which is why you see `ArrayList` turning out as `Object[]` on the other side. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Watson: For the record, I personally prefer sending a typed List/Array over the wire. If you want to stick with Arrays for the sake of client agnosticism, but want to use Lists while working with the data on the client then use LINQ or another method to transform the `RFData[]` received into `List<RFData>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your client-side configured as? You've displayed your server-side configuration, but don't forget that the client-side has it's own configuration settings.

Looking at your server-side configuration, it appears that the violation is occurring on the reception of the data on the client.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731745%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for an example. You can also do this programmatically as well.

**Edit**

Now I see in the comments that this `ArrayList` you are getting from the server contains your own user-defined type `RFData`. I believe now that this is likely the source of your problem.

Data Contracts describe the data that is being exchanged. Data Contracts are used between the Client and Server to serialize and de-serialize data that is being sent over the wire. You need to use Data Contracts/ Data Members when you are defining your own type to be used within the WCF model. Primitives as well as many of the built-in .NET types already have Data Contracts.

For your `RFData` type it would be something like this:

```
// Apply the DataContract to the type
[DataContract]
public class RFData
{
    // Apply the DataMemberAttribute to the various properties
    [DataMember]
    public double RFDouble { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int RFInt { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string RFString { get; set; }
}
```

I know you have several integers and doubles, but you get the gist. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a really helpful guide on Data Contracts from MSDN.

Comment: Hi Derek, thanks for your help. I don't have an app.config file in my project. Is there another way to retrieve this config file?

Comment: @Watson, you should make it clear what is your client/server project type. `app.config` is only available in some projects. For other projects you should see `web.config` or `servicereferences.clientconfig`. If your client project is a WinForms project, you can create `app.config` if it is not yet in the project.

Comment: Thanks for your help Derek, I really appreciate it. Please see my "Update" at the bottom of my post.

Comment: @DerekW see the above comment (forgot to tag)