# The underlying connection was closed - webAPI ,WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a REST Service calling a WCF service. The method in WCf service returns data as expected. Here is the Json format of the c#object.

```
 [
            {
                "$id": "1",
                "children": [],
                "id": 1,
                "name": "1",
                "owner": {
                    "userId": 1,
                    "username": "testuser",
                    "firstName": null,
                    "lastName": null
                },
                "parent": null,
                "permissions": [],
                "type": 0
            }
        ]
```

When There is a complex object the WCf service is throwing an error **"The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly"**

```
 [
    {
        "$id": "1",
        "Children": [
            {
                "$id": "2",
                "Children": [],
                "Id": 603268262,
                "Name": "testfolder",
                "Owner": {
                    "UserId": 555,
                    "Username": "testuser",
                    "FirstName": null,
                    "LastName": null
                },
                "Parent": {
                    "$ref": "1"
                },
                "Permissions": null,
                "Type": 0
            }
        ],
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "555",
        "Owner": {
            "UserId": 555,
            "Username": "testuser",
            "FirstName": null,
            "LastName": null
        },
        "Parent": null,
        "Permissions": null,
        "Type": 0
    }
]
```

I have tried most answers on this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285345/) question. Why do I get the error only when a complex object is returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer just after posting the question. I did notice that there is a object holding a reference to a object in the Json

```
"Parent": {
                    "$ref": "1"
                }
```

This is preventing the object from serialized. I did a deep copy and that fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

you need to check data contracts ,take a look at this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850.aspx